# Mass deleting white spaces with very large data arrays

Tags: excel, python-3.x, removing-whitespace

so i recently Dled a csv hthat is too large to use the mass delete found on the internet. How can i get rid of white spaces located between each data point. I can use python and someone had suggested something like:

```
for line in open('filename'):
    line = line.strip()
    if line.empty():
    continue
    print line
```

Yet when i try it the "empty" function doesn't seem to work. Either through python or any other way, I got to get rid of these white spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pointers:

- `line.strip()` only removes whitespace at the beginning and end of the line - is that    what you want? If you want all the whitespace removed, you could do something like `line = ''.join(line.split())`.
- Your `continue` lacks indentation.
- string objects don't have an `empty` method.
- To check if a string `mystr` is empty you can just issue `if mystr == ''` or `if not mystr` because empty strings evaluate to `false` in a boolean context.

Example code:

```
for line in open('filename'):
    line = line.strip()        
    if line:
        print(line)
```

Comment: hey thanks. Yeah i wanted to get it all removed. Another question I have would be how to download the statsmodel package in Python if I'm using a Mac? Or is that not a thing